# Mail Merge using the Data Bar Conditional Formatting

Tags: microsoft-word, mail-merge

I am creating a mail merge which produces customized reports for each student.  The content of the word document contains a bar which is marked off in units from the lowest possible to highest possible score.  I can easily put the students name and score onto the document merging the data from an excel spread sheet.  What I would like to do, however, is to indicate on that score bar where the students score fits. The conditional formatting "data bar" in excel would work for me.  I would just place it under the score bar and it would show where the students score fit on the bar.
I understand that I cannot merge formats using the mail merge.  However, is there a way to merge a "picture" of the formatted cell.   In other words, instead of merging text I would be picking up an "icon" from the spreadsheet and placing it in the appropriate place in the Word document. 
Thank-you

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following, but there are a number of provisos, e.g. it will probably only have a chance of working if you can merge to a new document, then update all the field codes. I have not covered all of the difficulties here.

I am assuming you are using Windows Word.

First, let's say your data is in "Sheet1", with a standard header row on row 1 and the data starting at row 2, with the score in column 5 and named "score"

Open the workbook in Excel

Set the workbook up to be the data source for the merge

In Excel, select the score in the first data row (row 2, column 5) and Edit->Copy

In Word, use Paste->Special to paste a link using the Picture format.

In Word, if you press Alt-F9, you should then see a field code something like this:

```
{ LINK Excel.Sheet.12 "C:\\mysheets\\databars1.xlsx" "Sheet1!R2C5" \a \p }
```

Select the "2" in "R2C5" and delete it, then...

use ctrl-F9 to insert a pair of the special field code brace characters so you have

```
{  }
```

click inside that and use ctrl-F9 again so you have

```
{ {  } }
```

Inside the inner braces, type MERGESEQ so you have

```
{ { MERGESEQ } }
```

Before the inner braces, type "=" and after, type "+1" so you have

```
{ ={ MERGESEQ }+1 }
```

(There are two fields that return row numbers realted to the data source. I won't go into the details here, but one of the advantages of { MERGESEQ } over { MERGEREC } in this case is that { MERGESEQ } has no value until you actually perform the merge.

If you now use Alt-F9 to redisplay the field result, and F9 to update it, you will probably see an error message.

Now merge to a new document. Again, you may have to take action to avoid errors. When the merge is complete, yoou will probably still see errors in the result. Use Alt-F9 - you should see LINK fields that have calculation fields like { =1+1 }, { =2+1 } in them.

Select the whole document and press F9 to update all the fields. You should see the bars from the relevant cells. Then select press shift-F9 to unlink all the fields (that will unlink other stuff too, so you may not want to do that.

A problem with Word is that it tends to destroy fields that are nested within LINK fields, either when you update the LINK field result, or when you save and re-open the document. I am fairly sure you will see that if you use { MERGEREC } instead of { MERGESEQ }. To guard against that, it may be helpful to change the LINK field so that it is no longer a LINK field before you save, and change it back when you re-open. e.g. change

```
{ LINK ... }
```

to

```
{ XLINK ... }
```

Obviously, at this point, the whole procedure has enough steps and difficulties that it would be difficult to hand to another user, but that's the only approach I know that has a chance of working. Otherwise, you either have to

- copy pictures from Excel (if there are only so many of them - if
  there are hundreds of different values I do not think it would be
  practical) and use something like an IF field to insert the relevant
  picture for each value. That would obviously reflect the formatting
  choices when you create your images, not in the sheet at merge time
  (e.g., what if you want to change the bar colour?)
  or
- use VBA and Word's MailMerge events (or postprocessing, if you are
  outputting to a new document) to go and get the right image for each
  row.

Comment: Than-you very much for the effort that you put into answering the question.  I am trying to work my way through it but get stuck very early on...  When I do an Alt F9, I do not get what you anticipated but instead only see   {SHAPE \* Mergeformat}..   FOr comparison,  For the other "standard" text fields I get things like  {MERGEFIELD first_Name \*MERGEFORMAT].  I must be not following your instructions correctly

Comment: Best guess: you haven't got to "Paste Special" yet. I don't have the screen in front of me, but in the Home tab, the Paste button probably has a drop down to a Paste->Special dialog, with options for "Paste" and "Paste Link". I suggest you explore pasting and linking with different formats - what you see may differ from what I see, which is why I do not like to give "Instructions" :-). When testing, you may need to redo your Edit->Copy in Excel before you paste in Word. I hope you'll get to see a { LINK } field, and then the rest of my previous post may begin to make sense.